# Has the ability to use let statements in do blocks been removed in GHC 8.6.5?

Tags: haskell, syntax, monads, let, do-notation

I have entered some code in `ghci`, similar to this:

```
main = do { a <- getLine ; let b = "Hello " ++ a ; putStrLn b }
```

However, I get this error:

```
<interactive>:1:63: error: parse error on input `}'
```

In previous versions of Haskell/GHC, I remember this working just fine - it was even explicitly said that, in `do` blocks, you don't need the `in` keyword. Yet, the only way to get this to work seems to be:

```
main = do { a <- getLine ; let b = "Hello " ++ a in putStrLn b }
```

which doesn't produce this error.

Has this been removed? If so, do I need a second `do` block inside the `let in` expression?

Comment: `main = do { a <- getLine ; let { b = "Hello " ++ a} ; putStrLn b }` works fine.

Comment: I think that's parsed as `do { a <- getLine ; let {b = "Hello " ++ a ; putStrLn b} }` if you don't put braces. After all, `do { a <- getLine ; let {b = "Hello " ++ a ; putStrLn b = ()} ; print 3 }` would be legal code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`let` is a layout keyword like `do`, both as a statement in a `do` block and in a `let`…`in`… expression, because it introduces a *block* of bindings. This:

```
main = do
  a <- getLine
  let b = "Hello " ++ a
  putStrLn b
```

Desugars to this:

```
main = do {
  a <- getLine;
  let {
    b = "Hello " ++ a;
  };
  putStrLn b;
};
```

Whereas what you’ve written is equivalent to this:

```
main = do {
  a <- getLine;
  let {
    b = "Hello " ++ a;
    putStrLn b
  };
};
```

So naturally GHC is expecting something else—a pattern or `=`—after `putStrLn b`, since you *could* be defining a local function named `putStrLn` with a parameter named `b`. The solution is either to use explicit braces in the `let` statement:

```
main = do { a <- getLine; let { b = "Hello " ++ a }; putStrLn b }
```

Or to use multiline mode in GHCi, either with the `:{` command, terminated with the `:}` command:

```
> :{
| main = do
|   a <- getLine
|   let b = "Hello " ++ a
|   putStrLn b
| :}
>
```

Or with `:set +m`, and terminated with a blank line:

```
> :set +m
| main = do
|   a <- getLine
|   let b = "Hello " ++ a
|   putStrLn b
|
>
```

Followed by `:unset +m` to return to single-line mode.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is here that it parses your `putStrLn b` as a `let` declaration as well, so it parses it basically as:

```
do { a <- getLine; let { b = "Hello " ++ a ; putStrLn b } }
```

It thus is looking for a `=` in the `putStrLn` part, where you will define the `putStrLn` function. The parser thus has the "idea" that you are defining a function, not calling a function.

Indeed, we can write for example:

```
Prelude> let a = 3; f b = b + 1
Prelude> f a
4
```

so here we declared two variables in the same line.

You can use curly brackets to make clear that the `let` is scoped to only `b`, like:

```
do { a <- getLine; let { b = "Hello " ++ a }; putStrLn b }
```

The priority of `let` is due to the grammar, defined in [Chapter 3: *Expressions* in the *Haskell'10 report*](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html).